# Laravel 5 routing-resource issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to use Laravel 5's resource inside group and it is not working

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'apps',
    'namespace' => 'App',
], function () {
    Route::resource('/', 'AppController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]);
    //but if I am adding something after / it works
    Route::resource('/asd', 'AppController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]);
    Route::get('/{slug}/{userId}', 'AppController@shared');
});
```

I am doing something wrong, or it is simply not allowed?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what's exactly not working?

Comment: Route::resource('/', 'AppController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]); for this route I am getting 404, I need that inside group, as I will have more routes starting with apps prefix

Comment: So, you go to 'example.com/apps/' and you get 404 error?

Comment: example.com/apps/slug and I need to get show method

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not gonna work. You could try to use:

```
Route::resource('something', 'AppController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]);
```

And then use URLs like `/apps/something/slughere` to call `@show` action.

You can look at your current working routes by calling this command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

If you'll run it now, you will see something like this:

```
apps/{}   |   apps..show
```

Which is not working route.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
Route::resource('/', 'AppController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]);
```

at the bottom